# Converting pid_t to string

Tags: c, string, pid

I am trying to convert a pid into a string. 
I tried it this way:

```
int pid = getpid(); //this int conversion should be ok as far as I know
char * mypid = (char *)malloc(sizeof(int));
sprintf(mypid, "%d", pid);
```

I assume that my mistake is maybe that I have not added a NULL in the end. I tried to do that but still got error messages. Can someone explain me what is the best way to but a PID into a char * ("string") ? Thanks!!

Comment: Why `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: "*still got error messages*" - What error messages?

Comment: @melpomene "segmentation fault" perhaps?

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc()` etc. - it is unnecessary and can also hide the erroneous lack of proper prototype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sizeof(int)` is most likely 4 bytes on your system.  A string containing a PID will need (assuming a 16 bit PID) at least 6 bytes: 5 for decimal digits and 1 for the null terminator.  So you're not allocating enough space and potentially writing past the end of the allocated array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Make sure you allocate enough space for the string in question:

```
int pid = getpid();
char * mypid = malloc(6);   // ex. 34567
sprintf(mypid, "%d", pid);
```

Or use a fixed size string:

```
int pid = getpid();
char mypid[6];   // ex. 34567
sprintf(mypid, "%d", pid);
```

If your system supports 32 bit PIDs, you'll need at least 11 bytes.  For 64 bit PIDs, at least 21.

Comment: You're assuming PIDs are limited to 16 bits.

Comment: @melpomene Correct, although I'm not aware of any systems that have larger PIDs.

Comment: Per [POSIX `sys/types.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html), `pid_t` can be as big as a `long`:  "The implementation shall support one or more programming environments in which the widths of `blksize_t`, `pid_t`, `size_t`, `ssize_t`, and `suseconds_t` are no greater than the width of type `long`."

Comment: @melpomene Good to know.  Updated to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

The mypid character array is not of the correct size. You are using `sizeof(int)` which is the number of bytes necessary to hold an integer on your system, not the string length of the integer. You could either count the number of digits if you want to be exact, or allocate a buffer of sufficient size, if exact storage is not a concern.

Correct and safe would be:

```
const size_t max_pid_len = 12; // Could be system dependent.
int pid = getpid();
char * mypid = malloc(max_pid_len + 1);
snprintf(mypid, max_pid_len, "%d", pid);
```

Answer (score 3):

`sprintf` will format the string and add a terminating zero for you, given sufficient buffer space to do so.

Your actual problem is this: `sizeof(int)` is not sufficient to hold the string value of any possible integer; that's just the length of an `int` in bytes on your system.  If an `int` is 32 bits on your system, you need to allocate at least 12 bytes to accommodate for the longest possible base-10 string representation (`-2147483648` plus the terminating zero). If an `int` is 64 bits, you need to allocate 21 bytes.

Comment: *you can probably omit the possibility of a minus sign being present in the string, though.* Strinctly speaking, [per POSIX that's not correct](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html).  "`blksize_t`, `pid_t`, and `ssize_t` shall be signed integer types."  I'll agree that it's **probably** safe, though, as I've never seen any implementation that creates negative PIDs.

Answer (score 3):

> to convert a pid into a string

`malloc(sizeof(int)` is the size of an `int` such as 4 bytes.  It is not the amount of memory to save as a decimal text in a string.

---

[`getpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) returns type `pid_t`.

Given `pid_t` is signed per [IEEE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/toc.htm) (it is buried deep) and [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/sys_types.h.0p.html), but of unknown width, it is reasonable to assume it is no wider than `intmax_t`.

Assigning a `pid_t` to an `int` can result in loss of information.

**The *minimal* allocation**

Let `asprintf()` allocate and convert to a string. [ref](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)

```
pid_t pid = getpid();
char *mypid = NULL;
if (asprintf(&mypid, "%jd", (intmax_t) pid) != -1) {
  // Success

  // use mypid somehow.

  free(mypid); // cleanup when done.
}
```